# Global `C-x C-f` binding is overridden

Tags: key-bindings, find-file, ido-find-file

I don't like `ido-find-file`, which seems to be the default response to `C-x C-f` in my Emacs 23.1.1 installation on Centos. I tried to change it in my `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'find-file)
```

This doesn't change anything, at least in either text mode or lisp mode.
What am I missing?

Comment: By default, C-x C-f does not run ido-find-file, not matter which version of Emacs. Maybe it's because you enable the ido-mode, and since the global keymap has the lowest priority, if C-x C-f is used in any non-global keymap (and the keymap is active), they will take effect, in this case, ido-mode's keymap already uses C-x C-f.

Comment: Thanks very much. I forgot that I had loaded better-defaults, which enables ido-mode. Modifying better-defaults fixed my complaint; you explained why.

Comment: @Drew I've provided an answer, as I think keymap priority is an important thing to know.

Answer (score 1):

`global-set-key` does not work because the same key is already used in ido-mode's kaymap, which has a higher priority than the global keymap, and the global keymap has the lowest priority. The solution, as you already know, is to keep ido-mode off, so ido-mode's keymap will not be active.